# Select last word in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just wondering if there is a way to select the last WORD in a DIV. I don't think there is any obvious way to do this, so are there any work arounds?

I don't mind using CSS or Javascript to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $div = $('div');    
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\w+?)$/, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/nQ5Y5/)

If the text inside the div does not contain any div element, then this will work. Otherwise, it won't, because it will replace all the previous elements with plain text.

Comment: it worked perfectly but if we have some diacritics it do not apply, why? some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`<div>` or no `<div>`, it boils down to basic String manipulation (using the [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)) method.

```
var words = $('#your_div').text().match(/(\w+)/g);
if (words.length) {
    var last_word = words[words.length - 1];
}
```

We build an array of all words using the `match()` method, and then get the last one (`var last_word = words[words.length - 1];`), but only if some words were found (`if (words.length)`).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I can't see how this can be used as a selector. I need to wrap the last word in a `<span>`. Maybe use `.replace()` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you are after another regular expression based solution, you could try (uses jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
        var $div = $(this);
        var text = $div.text(); // get the text of everything inside the div
        // the next line gets the last word followed only by non-word characters in that text
        // NB: the [\s\S] trick is to match any character, *including* new lines
        var last_word = $.trim(text).replace(/^[\s\S]*\b(\w+)\b[\W]*$/i, '$1');

        // this is from a jsFiddle I tried to post to test it.
        $('#output').append($div.attr('id') + ': Last word = ' + last_word + '<br />');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
var text = 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet';
var textSplit = text.split(' ');//split the text with space characters
var lastPart = textSplit.pop(); // retrieve the last word from the string
var firstPart = textSplit.join(' '); // retriece the words except the last word
var result = firstPart + '&nbsp;<strong>' + lastPart + '</strong>'; //join first part and last part and put the required html for the last word
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Javascript and HTML DOM to access the content of the div and then simply split the string (with a space as separator) and take the last split part.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this question:

**Demo:** http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7075397.htm

```
function getLastWord( words ) {
    lastWord = words.split( ' ' ).pop();
    return lastWord;
}

$( document ).ready( function() {
    theWords = $( '#theWords' ).html();
    lastWord = getLastWord( theWords );
    $( '#lastWord' ).html( lastWord );
} );
```

**SCOPE CREEP!**
Given the new requirements to dynamically inject the span tag, I've modified the code as follows (I've also updated my demo):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    theWords = $( '#theWords' ).html();
    lastWord = getLastWord( theWords );
    appendCon = '#lastWord';
    $( appendCon) .append( $( '<span> '+lastWord+'</span>' ) );
} );
```

Comment: the problem with this is I need the `<span>` to be added automatically. The content is going to be added dynamically by Wordpress.