# How to add span element around the word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add span element around last word of the title using with jQuery.

I want output like this:

```
<div class="hedererty">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing <span>elit</span></h1>
</div>
```

Note: This is example title. In my site title is changing with different pages.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: See this will give you the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075397/select-last-word-in-a-container `:)`

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788939/jquery-find-and-wrap-textnode-with-some-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.hedererty h1').html(function(idx, html){
    return html.replace(/(\w+)$/, '<span>$1</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rXRtm/)

or

```
$('.hedererty h1').html(function (idx, html) {
    return html.replace(/(\s[\S]+)$/, '<span>$1</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eNQQD/)

Comment: I didn't knew this was asked by Rakinikanth :D

Answer (score 1):

`split()` the string, add the `span` to the popped string and concatenate the string using `join()`

```
$(".hedererty h1").html(function(){
    var mystring= $(this).text().split(" "); //Split the string
    var lastword = mystring.pop(); //Pop the last index value
    return mystring.join(" ")+ (mystring.length > 0 ? " <span>"+ lastword + "</span>" : lastword); 
    //Return concatenated string
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QXZPS/)